# transpose a file using a key field in awk

Tags: awk, transpose

I want to use awk to transpose a file over a group field. Tks

I have a file like this.

```
id  Name    Value

1 B1 0.1

1 B2 0.3

1 B3 0.4

2 B1 0.2

2 B2 0.09

2 B3 0.10
```

I want a file like this:

```
   B1 B2 B3
 1 0.1 0.3 0.4
 2 0.2 0.09 0.10
```

Comment: You will get a much friendlier reception on SO if you show what code you have tried so far and what went wrong with it.

Comment: Normally, I do that in R, but I had a problem with the limit of rows, because I have a big file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR==1 { next }
(prev != "") && ($1 != prev) {
    if (++nr == 1) {
        print hdr
        rec = prev rec
    }
    print rec
    hdr = ""
    rec = $1
}
{
    hdr = hdr OFS $2
    rec = rec OFS $3
    prev = $1
}
END { print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
        B1      B2      B3
1       0.1     0.3     0.4
2       0.2     0.09    0.10
```